# Reload article translation without refreshing page - Vue

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

ArticleController

```
public function index()
    {
        $locale = Lang::locale();
        // $locale =   Lang::getLocale();
        $articles = Article::withTranslations($locale)->get();
        return $articles;
    }
```

resources/assets/js/pages/articles/Index.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
      <div v-for="article in articles" :key="article.articles">
          <div v-for="translation in article.translations">
              <h4>{{ translation.title }}</h4>
              {{ translation.subtitle }}
              {{ translation.content }}
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'

    export default {
        layout: 'basic',

        data: function () {
            return {
                articles: []
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            var app = this;
            axios.get('/api/articles')
                .then(response => {
                  // JSON responses are automatically parsed.
                  this.articles = response.data
                })
                .catch(e => {
                  this.errors.push(e)
                })
        }
    }
</script>
```

This displays the article according to the current language detected on the frontend (Vue). When i change the language with a switcher, the article does not automatically translate. I have to manually reload the page for the article to show in the new selected language. How to reload the new language without refreshing the page in vue

Comment: Where are you changing the language?

Comment: @acdcjunior On the frontend ( vue) i have installed "vue-i18n": "^7.6.0", and created a language switcher component, The controller code detects the language in the vue and displays articles based on the locale code from database. However, when i change the language to espanol it does not show espanol article and still stays on english until i do a refresh

Comment: Tipically you would add that code you have at `mounted()` at a watcher.  A watcher for `language` if language is the variable the idiom is stored at. Of course, this approach only works when there exists such variable.

Comment: could you provide an example as i do not find any related tutorial or article references

Comment: Do like this: show the language switcher and how it relates to the code you already have in the question (relates in "does it import it?" "do they have a component that imports both i18n and the one you are showing?")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand well, but...

You want to change the article text acoording to the user preference language but you are not sending to a controller a language param and you dont capture any lang param.
I think you can do something like this

ArticleController

```
public function index($locale) // you'll need to modify your route or you can use the Request $request, in that case $locale = $request->locale
{
    // $locale = Lang::locale();
    // $locale =   Lang::getLocale();
    $articles = Article::withTranslations($locale)->get();
    return $articles;
}
```

resources/assets/js/pages/articles/Index.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        Select Your Language
        <select v-model="language"> 
            <option @click="changeLang('english')">english</option>
            <option @click="changeLang('spanish')">spanish</option>
            <option @click="changeLang('italian')">italian</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    import axios from 'axios'

        export default {
            layout: 'basic',

            data: function () {
                return {
                    articles: [],
                    language: 'english'
                }
            },
            mounted() {
                this.getArticles ()
            },
            methods: {
                changeLang (lang) {
                    // at change set new lang and obtain articles again with the new lang setting
                    this.language = lang
                    this.getArticles ()
                },
                getArticles () {
                    var app = this;
                    axios.get('/api/articles', {locale: this.language}) // Send lang param to a controller
                        .then(response => {
                        // JSON responses are automatically parsed.
                        this.articles = response.data
                        })
                        .catch(e => {
                        this.errors.push(e)
                        })
                }
            }
        }
</script>
```

I really hope that this answer help you

Comment: i have tries this before but it didn't work as i received an error that i cannot define lanaguage twice in route. Im using this starter template, please check https://github.com/cretueusebiu/laravel-vue-spa

Comment: my route is Route::resource('articles/{locale}', 'Articles\ArticleController'); and the error i get Route pattern "/api/articles/{locale}/{{locale}}" cannot reference variable name "locale" more than once.The locale is automatically added in the url in the starter template i used)

Comment: Nooooo, I think you need to read again the Route documentation.

Comment: first define resources route Route::resource('articles', 'Articles\ArticleController');

Comment: then define index resource route Route::get('articles/{locale}', 'Articles\ArticleController@index');

Comment: or only define resources routes and capture locale data using the Request $request

Comment: I tried a different way. Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49346221/watch-the-locale-and-fetch-articles-again-vuejs/49346586#49346586

Comment: What is that??????  mmm I think you're writing code without thinking well about what you're doing.  My advice is that first you work on how to get the data you need in the back and once that works you start to work in the front (vue).  
I'm not working in your project and for that reason I could not understand your needs and I could not help you more depth.

Comment: That's alright! I finished up the localization and the project too. I'm trying to keep the localization completely in the frontend and just use the locale value to be fetched in the backend to pull articles according to the locale. It might confuse as i do not have {language} in the route specified. But thats automatically added. Check this template https://github.com/cretueusebiu/laravel-vue-spa

Comment: This was an existing project for which im just changing the frontend to vue. Backend works perfect

Comment: to be honest with you, I do not have time to analyze the code of an entire project that I'm not working on.
it may be that the repository code works perfectly, but there is something you want to do that I'm not understanding well.